# linux - Problems installing SSL cert - Apache2

Tags: linux, ssl, apache2

HI there,

So I followed this tutorial: http://www.tc.umn.edu/~brams006/selfsign_ubuntu.html

step by step in installing a Thawte cert... however on attempting to restart apache I get the following:

- Restarting web server apache2
  [Mon Aug 31 14:20:23 2009] [warn] NameVirtualHost *:443 has no VirtualHosts
  httpd (pid 10117?) not running

Any ideas on what i might have done wrong?

REgards,
Fiona

Comment: Probably want to try serverfault

Comment: Thank you Mike. Didn't know about this site!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem in the past, I think you need to put the IP of you server instead of an asterisk in your virtual host configuration.